# How to analyse extremely low sample pre/post test data?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, t-test

So the study involves assessments, then an intervention, and then the same assessments. There are two groups, 2 in one group, 1 in the other. Data is not binary but consists of scores on the assessments. Is the sample size too small to run any statistical analysis? Am I better off just reporting percentage change for now until I get more participants?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need more than 3 subjects. Especially if one group only has one subject.

Depending on how hard it would be for you to get more subjects, i would advise between 15 and 30 subjects at least.

You cant run any statistical analysis until you have more than 3 participants